# Is this the right way to skip a line in a text file?

Tags: c

Working on a project regarding a booking system. This function is to delete a line in a text file. When I run this, nothing happens.

CustomerD.txt is for recording all students who delete the booking.
Backup.txt is for temporary file.

```
int del()
{
    FILE *in, *out, *stay;
    char ch, conf;
    int  temp = 0;
    int id;
    in = fopen("Customer.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("Backup.txt", "w+");
    stay = fopen("CustomerD.txt","w+");
    if (in == NULL)
     {
       printf("\nCannot Open the Source file");
         exit(1);
      } 
    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("\nCannot create Target File\n");
        exit(1);
        }
     printf("Enter your id :");
    scanf("%d", &id);
   ch = fgetc(in);
   while (ch!= EOF)
    {
        if (id!=s->id)
    {
        ch = fgetc(in);
        fputc(ch, out);
    }
    else {
        ch = fgetc(in);
        fputc(ch, stay);
    }
    }
    printf("Your Deletion is done");
    fclose("Customer.txt");
fclose("Backup.txt");
fclose("CustomerD.txt");
remove("Customer.txt");
if (remove("Customer.txt") == 0)
    printf("Deleted successfully");
else
    printf("Unable to delete the file");
rename("Backup.txt","Customer.txt");
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you expect `if (id!=s->id)` to work? Neither variable changes, or is affected during the loop. Note that `char ch` should be `int ch`.

Comment: Indent your code properly. Your code is unreadable and therefore it's hard to understand. Also for deleting a line in a file you should read/write the files line by line, not char by char: proceed like this: for each line read in file A : if the line does not meet the deletion  criteria then write it to file B, otherwise don't.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for the mistake. I just started learning C for 2 weeks.

Comment: When twice deleting the file with `remove("Customer.txt"); if (remove("Customer.txt") == 0)` the second one won't report correctly (it was already deleted).

Comment: If you want to remove a line from a text file I suggest you read it line by line using `fgets()` and check its content to see what should be done with the line.

Comment: You might want to read the manpage for `fclose` again. Your compiler should show some warnings: `fclose("Backup.txt");`

Comment: If you're working with lines, use a function that reads lines — `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` for example.  Or, if you must, write your own function that reads a line and then returns it for the higher-level program to work on.  Working down at the character-by-character input level is mixing levels and makes life unnecessarily hard for yourself.